# named queries in hibernate 3 only?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have read in a book saying that named queries are introduced in version 3 of hibernate only. However I remember using them in Hibernate 2. Can someone validate which is correct?

Comment: +1 Legitimate question since a supposed reference for Hibernate has shared information which one could doubt.

Comment: Which book. Without knowing, we can not tell whether there is a fault in the book or a fault in your comprehension of the book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I believe this documentation of the API, I would say that named queries were there back in version 2.0.

[Hibernate API Documentation](http://www.dil.univ-mrs.fr/~massat/docs/hibernate-2/api/index.html)

Yet, it is not clearly mentioned, I believe only since I found this link for a search to "Hibernate 2.0 documentation" on Google, and it is not the same documentation of the actual version, plus it mentions `hibernate-2` in the URL.

Comment: found the hibernate 2.1.8 javadoc here (http://www.jdocs.com/hibernate/2.1.8/net/sf/hibernate/Session.html#M-getNamedQuery(String)) and the session class has a method getNamedQuery()

Comment: This proves that my belief was founded, and particularly yours, shall I mention! =)